# Let $f(x)$ be a fourth differentiable function such that $f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, then $f^{(4)}(0)$ is equal to?

Tags: functions, derivatives, functional-equations

> Let $f(x)$ be a fourth differentiable function such that $f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, then $f^{(4)}(0)$ is equal to?

**Solution Given in text book:**

Replace $x$ by $(-x)$ in given relation

$f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$

So in final he obtained $x[f(x)+f(-x)]=0$ and from here deducted that $f(x)$ is an odd function.

**My doubt:**

How can we surely say that $f(x)+f(-x)=0$?

Can we obtain function from given relation?

Comment: You're implicitly assuming that $x\neq 0$ when you divide by $x$. When you finish the problem, you're going to have to exclude $x=0$ until you decide whether or not it can stay. I'm not sure what $f(x)$ is, but it might have a discontinuity at $x=0$. In other words, $f(x)$ is an odd function when $x\neq 0$.

Comment: but in text book it is not given that $x \neq 0$

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous function such that $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ for all $x \neq 0$ then this equation also holds for $x=0$. Just take limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, Also can we obtain the function using given relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no doubt that $f(x)$ is an odd function when $x\neq 0$. So let's consider the situation when $x=0$.

Firstly, given that $f(x)$ is a fourth differentiable function, $f(x)$ is necessarily continuous (at every point where it is differentiable). Thus we have the following equality according to the definition:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \\
&=\lim_{-x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{-x\to 0+}\frac{-f(-x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{-f(x)-f(0)}{-x}
\end{align*}
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-\frac{-f(x)-f(0)}{-x}=\lim_{x\to 0+}-\frac{2f(0)}{x}=0$$
We get $f(0)=0$

Comment: just by $f(0)=0$ we can't say it is odd

Comment: @mathophile You have obtained $x[f(x)+f(-x)]=0$. If $x\neq 0$, we have $f(x)+f(-x)=0$, i.e. $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for all $x \neq 0$. If $x=0$, my post has shown $f(0)=0$. As $f(0)=-f(-0)=0$, $f(x)=-f(-x)$ holds for all x. That's exactly the definition of odd functions.